# What does Ruby's using method do?

Tags: ruby, using

Metaprogramming Ruby chapter 3 has a task to write a Ruby equivalent of C#'s [`using` statement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/yh598w02.aspx). I started:

```
class Resource
  def dispose
    @disposed = true
  end
  def disposed?
    @disposed
  end
end
def using(r)
  puts "Not implemented."
end

r = Resource.new
using(r)
```

I have not implemented `using` yet. Nevertheless, when I run this code, I get

```
in `using': wrong argument type Resource (expected Module) (TypeError)
```

Furthermore, if I write something like `using(Kernel)`, `using(Enumerable)`, etc., the program finishes without error. As far as I know, there is no `using` method or keyword in Ruby, but I also get the same behaviour in pry and irb. What is happening?

Comment: I get 'Not implemented.' when I run the code above, works for me the way it should in 1.9.3

Comment: what ruby version are you running? there should not be a method called `using` in later MRI versions

Comment: You can see [here](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/doc/syntax/refinements_rdoc.html), when we need to use `using` method.`using` take as it arguments the module name.. not the object. You got the error, as you pass it the instance of `Resource`.`using` is used to activate the refinement. See this blog also [`Refining Ruby`](http://blog.headius.com/2012/11/refining-ruby.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to do that in Ruby 2.1 you will need to patch the `main` object, as it already has the method like it's mentioned in the comments:

```
self.instance_eval do
  def using(r)
    puts "Not implemented."
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

There should not be a `using` method as pointed out in the comments. Try running `method(:using).owner` to see if you get any more information. The expected result on irb is

```
"NameError: undefined method `using' for class `Object'"
```

but you should get the source of your using.